# Edit after workflow approved

Tags: security, workflow, permissions

I just watched a tutorial on how to set up Workflows here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFDUgiQCTmU&list=PLfRWjEN_vCUZqAk8ks5j36yM-BCWup-SZ&index=1#t=35m58s

I followed this tutorial through to 35m58s and it worked great:

- Created Content Editor and Content Manager Roles (Manager can publish)
- Set up a workflow with Draft, Awaiting Approval and Approved states.
- Set up actions allowing the roles to move to next steps as appropriate.
- Assigned workflow to my general page template

It works great, however after the Content Manager approves the revision and publishes as per the video, the Content Editor is not able to edit the page or add a version. I see the following message on the page editor screen:

[image: Error Message]

Could anyone elaborate on how to allow Content Editors to edit or create a subsequent version?

Comment: Is there an "edit" button on the "review" tab?

Comment: There is not. The workflow  section of the review tab just says 'this item has been approved', and has a 'history' button. That's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So one thing I missed from my video was how to configure the roles for having access to various workflow states.  You need to open the `Security Editor` and make sure to select the correct role to edit.

In this case you will want to edit the `Content Editor` role.  You will need to do two things to ensure that the `Content Editor` role can make changes.

1. You need to make sure the content in your tree has `Write` Access for the correct role, in this case `Content Editor`.
2. Make sure that you give `Content Editor`, the privilege to `Workflow State Write` for the workflow state they should have access to.

If you don't see the column for Workflow State Write, you can click on the Columns button in the Security Editor, and then you can make changes to it's workflow state write.

[image]

One other thing to note about workflow, if you are adding it to an existing content tree, is that the items that were added before you added workflow, will not be assigned to the default state of workflow by default.  If you would like to update your content, you can either do that manually, or you can use SPE to update the content.

You can also use the Access Viewer to view the changes you are making to confirm things have the correct access you are looking for.  Or you can start an incognito window and login to a user's account that has the `Content Editors` role assigned to it, so you can confirm they have the access you are looking for.

Comment: @Dylan-young is there a way we can have a Reviewer role that can just accept/reject workflow and dont have write access to content item