How to Prevent User Edits on a Sitecore Item After Submission for Approval
In our Sitecore CMS, we are facing a challenge where after a user edits an item and submits it for approval, other users are still able to edit the same item before it's approved. This results in multiple users' edits being bundled into one approval process, which is not desirable.
How can we configure Sitecore to lock the item from further edits once it has been submitted for approval?
Steps to Reproduce:

User 1 edits an item and submits it for approval.
The item is now pending approval but still open for edits.
User 2 is also able to edit the same item during its pending approval status.

We are using Sitecore with a standard workflow setup. Any insights on how to lock the item post-submission to prevent further edits until the approval is complete would be greatly appreciated.

Did you check this? Looks like this is what you are looking for.
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9654/edit-after-workflow-approved

You can use Workflow State Write feature which deny/allow access to edit the item when the item is in that particular state.
You can create a custom role that would deny access to edit as below, on the Awaiting Approval state item. This role can be then assigned to the User.
/sitecore/system/Workflows/Sample Workflow/Awaiting Approval


Using above changes, you can make sure item can't be edited on the Awaiting Approval state.
You can find more details for the same here.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/latest/sitecore-experience-manager/workflow-and-security-features.html
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
